# Can I get list of both posts and subcategories in AZ order?

Tags: php, wordpress, list, categories, posts

I have category that looks like this:

category 1

- subcategory 1

  - post 1-1
  - post 1-2
- another subcategory 2

  - post 2-1
- post 1
- post 2
- post 3

What I'm trying to achieve is list of posts and subcategories from category 1:

- another subcategory 2
- post 1
- post 2
- post 3
- subcategory 1

i.e. in **alphabetical order** and **without** posts from subcategories.

I can get list of subcategories (using get_categories), I can get list of posts (using get_posts) but I'm not able to get both (subcategory and post) in one list that can be in A-Z order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the arrays with array_merge, then use usort to alphabetize.  You won't find a standard function that does this for you.